# Why is this PHP script the JSON results when I haven't told it to?

Tags: php, json, curl

So I'm using the only source I've found for sending a post request to Google QPX API. I want to save it in a json_decoded PHP array, but for some reason the `$result = curl_exec($ch);` line doesn't work, and the json prints onscreen anyways.

Is there something I'm not understanding that is happening in the cURL? Thanks!

```
$data = array ( "request" => array(
            "passengers" => array( 
                    adultCount => 1
                        ),
                    "slice" => array( 
                            array(
                                origin => "BOS",
                                destination => "LAX",
                                date => "2015-09-09"),
                            array(
                                origin => "LAX",
                                destination => "BOS",
                                date => "2015-09-10"),
                            ),
                                solutions => "10"
                            ),
             );
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=MY-API-KEY');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You're asking for json data in the curl options. So $result is json. You could do json_decode($result, true) to get PHP array

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
```

> **`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`** - `TRUE` to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it out directly.
>
> http://php.net/curl_setopt

Set this option to `true` if you want to save the result in a variable.